# Cassandra, Spark, Elasticsearch: streaming data for visualisation in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, streaming, apache-spark

I am trying to visualise data from spark in Kibana. However, creating an RRD by using the following:

```
    val test = sc.cassandraTable("test","data")
```

Then I used the Elasticsearch and Hadoop library to stream to Elasticsearch with following:

```
    EsSpark.saveToEs(test, "spark/docs", Map("es.nodes" -> "192.168.1.88"))
```

but i get this error:

```
15/04/20 16:15:27 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 12.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 12.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 12.0 (TID 36, 192.168.1.92): org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.EsHadoopSerializationException: Cannot handle type [class com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow]
```

Could anyone guide me to streaming from spark to Elasticsearch. Is there any better way to visualize data from cassandra, solr or spark. I came across banana but it does not seem to have option for publishing dashabords.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [Spark Cassandra Connector Guide](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/6_advanced_mapper.md), you can first define a case class, then convert the CassandraRow to the case class objects, then save the objects to Elasticsearch. Below is the sample code from the guide:

```
case class WordCount(w: String, c: Int)

object WordCount { 
    implicit object Mapper extends DefaultColumnMapper[WordCount](
        Map("w" -> "word", "c" -> "count")) 
}

sc.cassandraTable[WordCount]("test", "words").toArray
// Array(WordCount(bar,20), WordCount(foo,10))

sc.parallelize(Seq(WordCount("baz", 30), WordCount("foobar", 40)))
  .saveToCassandra("test", "words", SomeColumns("word", "count"))
```